# How to determine if a value exists in a map of maps

Tags: elixir

I have the following elixir map used to represent a matrix of int/bool tuples. Using a map is desirable as I want to use access behaviour e.g. matrix[0][3].

```
matrix = %{
  0 => %{
    0 => {22, false},
    1 => {13, false},
    2 => {17, false},
    3 => {11, false},
    4 => {0, false}
  },
  1 => %{
    0 => {8, false},
    1 => {2, false},
    2 => {23, false},
    3 => {4, false},
    4 => {24, false}
  },
  2 => %{
    0 => {21, false},
    1 => {9, false},
    2 => {14, false},
    3 => {16, false},
    4 => {7, false}
  }
}
```

I want to write a function that will give me the row and column of a given number in the map e.g.

```
get_position(22) # { 0, 0 }
get_position(16) # { 2, 3 }
```

I could use a list comprehension to do this e.g.

```
  def get_position (matrix, n) do
    for {i, row} <- matrix, {j, {^n, _}} <- row, do: {i, j}
  end
```

This is inefficient as all values are accessed. Is there a more efficient way to do this i.e. stop the iterations when the value is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3)

```elixir
Enum.reduce_while(matrix, nil, fn
  {ok, ov}, nil ->
    ov
    |> Enum.reduce_while(nil, fn
      {ik, {22, _}}, nil -> {:halt, {ok, ik}}
      _, _ -> {:cont, nil}
    end)
    |> case do
      nil -> {:cont, nil}
      found -> {:halt, found}
    end
  _, _ -> {:cont, nil}
end)

#⇒ {0, 0}
```

---

Another way would be to use [`try/throw/catch`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#try/1-catch-clauses)

```elixir
try do
  for {ok, ov} <- matrix, {ik, {iv, _}} <- ov, iv == 16,
    do: throw {ok, ik} 
catch
  e -> e
end

#⇒ {2, 3}
```

Comment: The nested reduce_while blocks look hideous but is exactly what I asked for, thanks

Comment: `try/throw/catch` is a way better and way more idiomatical approach.